# How will C++20 constexpr containers work?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, constexpr, c++20

As [`constexpr std::string`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0980r0.pdf) and [`constexpr std::vector`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1004r1.pdf) have been accepted into C++20, how will these be used? The linked papers are very short on details. Do we need to specify special `constexpr` allocators, making compile-time strings/vectors incompatible with their normal equivalents?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those two papers depend heavily on [P0784](https://wg21.link/P0784), which discusses how allocations at compile-time will work.

Incomplete answer:

- Only `std::allocator` will work.
- All allocations are tracked, and must be deallocated before compilation is complete. This means that you can do manipulations at compile-time, but you can't initialize `string` and `vector` variables to be used at run-time. (Personally, I think there's a good chance that this restriction will be lifted in a future version of the standard - but that's just my opinion.)